# Any time and Any day in english

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

**1) Can we use ‘any time’ instead of ‘any day’ in the below example?**

"Have you seen this any day before?"

Can you please tell me what the difference is between ‘any time’ and ‘any day’?

**2) Answer this question: Shall I come next week?**

A) You can come at any time.

B) You can come on any day.

C) You can come on any week.

Which one of the above is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look in a dictionary for the words **time** and **day** you will certainly see the difference.

As for using **any day** instead of **any time**, well, yes, it's possible:

- You can come at any time. *(or You can come anytime)*
- You can come (on) any day. *(the preposition is optional and I always omit it)*

Both are correct.

The first sentence you wrote is really awkward, I would rephrase it using **ever**-

- Have you ever seen this before?

Comment: Well i appreciate your answer, but i have question like, if i use ‘at any time’ instead of ‘on any day’ in that example, does it alter the meaning or the meaning remains same?  as i think ‘time’ only restricts a particular day and ‘day’ can be anything, also i have seen using ‘any time’ in the situations where the questions are asked for a day like ‘can i can tomorrow morning?’ in such case answer will be ‘come at any time’ but when question is asked ‘can i come tomorrow ‘ the answer i have seen like ‘ come on any day’ so my question is like if i use ‘at any time’ instead if ‘on any day’?

Comment: While the literal meaning of "come at any time" and "come on any day" is the same.  The context implies something different.  If you answer "... any day" you probably understand the expected time.  If you answer "any time" you are emphasising that there is no expected time.